# How Do You Clone A VM Using VMware Fusion?

Tags: macos, vmware

Is it possible to clone a virtual machine using VMware Fusion on Mac OS X? I'm trying the 30 day evaluation version but there doesn't appear to be a clone feature. I tried using the Finder to copy a VM's package structure but the copy didn't appear in the Virtual Machine Library.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use File->open to open the copy of the VM.  It will probably ask you if you want to change the VM's unique ID.  If you plan to run both the original and the clone at the same time, and it's not a Windows OS that needs activation, you should say yes.

Comment: tips: vm file is usually located in ~/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized directory.

Comment: I just tried that on VMware Fusion 5.0.3. It opens the existing VM. It does not clone or copy the existing VM.

Comment: I have to add this note that before copying files, make sure that the vm is shutdown or suspended.

Comment: You need to shutdown your VM and manually copy the file located in ~/Documents/Virtual Machines. Only then you can use File->open to open the clone. @stephen-weasler's solution does not involve manual copy-paste

Answer (score 14):

1. In the Virtual Machine Library window select the add button (upper left)
2. Select "New"
3. Select "Continue without Disc" button
4. Select "Use an existing virtual disk:"
5. browse to where the Vm you want to clone is located. On the bottom half of the screen you have 3 options. To create a totally separate VM select the first one " Make a separate copy of the viral disk" and just follow the instructions.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Works great on VMware Fusion 5.0.3. Its too bad VMware does not even put an entry in its help file for "clone."

Comment: Works for VMware Fusion 8.1.1

Answer (score 4):

just copy the folder cp -R folder newfolder (in your docs folder) Open the folder in Vmware and say you copied it   Have a look on weblog.jamisburk.org, august 15

as there may be issues with networking

Justin

Comment: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/8/15/cloning-ubuntu-hardy-image-in-vmware-fusion

Comment: That's correct: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1001524

Answer (score 2):

I don't know fusion in detail, but in VMWare Server you can just copy the files somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah just copy the file, and then when you open the file VMWare asks you if this has been copied. Easy as! Thx

Answer (score 2):

Here are the instructions on VMware's site:

http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1001524

> To copy the virtual machine:
>
> 1. Power off your virtual machine.
>      **Note**: Making a copy of a virtual machine while it is running or
>      suspended can create a copy that may not boot.
> 2. Find the virtual machine bundle. For more information, see [Locating
>      the virtual machine bundle in VMware Fusion (1007599)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1007599).
> 3. Drag the virtual machine bundle to the location where you want the
>      copied bundle to be. If you are copying it to the same folder or
>      somewhere else on your hard drive, hold down the **option** key -- this
>      tells Mac OS to copy the file rather than moving it. If you are moving
>      the bundle to another drive or a network share, Mac OS copies the file
>      automatically. The cursor is superimposed with a green circle and a
>      plus sign, indicating that a copy will be made.
>     
>      **Note**: This does not affect your current virtual machine.
>
> If you power
>   on the copied virtual machine, Fusion asks if you have moved the
>   virtual machine or copied it. Select that you **Moved It** (unless you
>   need to run the copied virtual machine at the same time as the
>   original). This indicates that it is the same virtual machine, just
>   starting from a new location, and keeps all of the settings the same.
>
> **Note**: When you select the **Copied It** option, a new UUID and MAC address
>   are generated, which can cause Windows to require re-activation and
>   may cause network issues.